# Assembler patching compare istructions and branch

Tags: assembly, arm, patch, cmp, ida

How Can I make "true" this istrution?

```
CMP             R0, #0
```

What I want to do is for example make

```
CMP R0,R0 or CMP #0, #0
```

00 28 is the op code. I try to do `28 28` without results!
Another question
what kind of istructions is `BNE.W`? what this the final W?
How can I mod that in a BE? op code is `40 F0 65 85`

NOTE: All op codes are in thumb mode!

***** EDIT
Does exists an armv7 compiler for Mac?

Comment: What CPU is this for??? Add the appropriate tag.

Comment: Assemble the instruction `CMP R0, R0` or `CMP #0, #0` and replace the above opcode with this one.

Comment: nice solution! How can I do that if it is for an arm7 processor? And It use thumb mode... Can you tell me something for BNE.W? What kind of istruction is it?

Comment: Use any sort of ARMv7 assembler you have to compile the code and extract the opcode. I've never done any ARM work before so I don't know what thumb mode is, but the `W` usually means WORD. Anyway, I'm probably wrong but try `80 42` for `CMP R0, R0`. That's what I came up with from quickly looking at an ARMv5 manual. I came up with `00 28` from `CMP R0, #0` so it might actually be right (or not).

Comment: this is an armv7 not arm7, huge difference (arm7 does not have thumb2 mode only thumb).  Everything you need to know is in one of the armv7 architectural reference manuals (ARM ARM) avaiable at infocenter.arm.com under architectural reference.  the .w is shown quite clearly in the manual, it implies a larger constant, thumb one bne is a 8 bit or 11 bit immediate, thumb2 gives 17 or 21 bit immediate.  the .w sorta implies a thumb2 instruction instead of thumb, which is a word in size instead of a halfword. so .w means word.

Comment: I must be registered to take a look at the manual!! Do you have a copy?

Comment: If you Google "armv7-r" there's an ARMv7-A/R manual about 4 links down. Out of curiosity, did `80 42` work?

Comment: Yes thanks!!! the 80 42 opcode is for Ida Pro CMP R0, R0

Comment: Does exists a table with most important Istructions and their respective opcode?

Comment: @UsiUsi: I posted an answer of how I came up with `80 42` using a reference manual. As I mentioned it's much quicker to assemble `CMP R0, R0` to get the opcode but this is another way when you can't do that. Also, since your using IDA, I'm sure there'd be some option to replace an instruction with `CMP R0, R0`, rather than having to figure out the opcodes yourself.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will look fo that option!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply assemble `CMP R0, R0` or `CMP #0, #0` and extract the needed opcode from those instructions that way.

Another way is to look at an ARM reference manual and manually build up the opcode. [This](http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~cs9242/11/doc/armv5_ref.pdf) is an ARMv5 manual I quickly found and under `7.1.22` you have `CMP <Rn>, <Rm>` with details of building the opcode for comparing two registers. The details seem to be the same as an ARMv7 manual I also found just before I was about to post.

It has bits 15-6 being `0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0`, then bits 5-3 are the number of the first register (number 0 represented by 3 bits for `R0`), and bits 2-0 being the second register (also `R0`). So your opcode would now be:

`0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0` (`CMP`) `000` (`R0`) `000` (`R0`)

`100001010000000` in hex is `4280`, therefore in little-endian order the two bytes you need are `80 42`.

As you can see, it'd be a lot quicker to just let an assembler work that out for you.